# Data table filtros

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, filtro

Tengo una duda hice una datatable funciona bien y a cada columna se puede filtrar mi duda es como puedo hacer que filtre no solo una vez ejemplo: en la columna están 3 colores azul, rojo y amarillo entonces filtro por azul y coloca las azules pero también quiero que filtre las amarillas al mismo tiempo pero al colocar la palabra azul y amarilla no me filtra nada solo puede filtrar o el azul o el amarillo pero no ambos , mi pregunta es se puede filtrar dos o más palabras?

Comment: puedes hacerlo con un filtro personalizado checa la guía http://jsfiddle.net/ca6Zc/

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]